# Defaultdict - assign strings to key value in loop

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I am struggling to understand why the string values I am trying to loop through and assign to dictionary key-value pairs in a default dictionary are not properly working.

The desired outcome here is to loop through the string values in each of the two lists, and return a dictionary that has websites for keys and team names for values. However, neither append nor the equal sign work.  In addition, I am not sure why the defaultdict returns of the form defaultdict(None, {}) (or defaultdict(list, {}) if i initiate it as a list). Is there a way to assert that both the keys and values of this dict will be strings?

Thank you for your help.

```
teams=['yankees','redsox','giants']
websites=['xasfsgrwg.cc','redsox.com','giants.org']

from collections import defaultdict 
baseballdict=defaultdict() #defaultdict(None, {})
#baseballdict=defaultdict(list)

for i in range(len(websites)):
    baseballdict[websites[i]]=baseballdict[teams[i]] #does not work 
    baseballdict[websites[i]].append(baseballdict[teams[i]]) # does not work
```

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49968576/edit) your question with your desired output? This will add some clarity to your question.

Comment: `dict(zip(webites, teams))`

Comment: If you've explained your desired result correctly then (1) Stephen's comment is the best way (2) a defaultdict doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong assigning and appending   in last lines of your code.

This is a fix for your code.

```
teams=['yankees','redsox','giants']
websites=['xasfsgrwg.cc','redsox.com','giants.org']

baseballdict={}

for i in range(len(websites)):
    baseballdict[websites[i]]=teams[i] 

print(baseballdict)# prints dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a defaultdict that has the type string as the key type, you should create like `my_dict = defaultdict(str)`. And for having a dictionary that has the websites as keys and teams as values you should do:

```
for i in range(len(websites)):
    baseballdict[websites[i]] = teams[i]
```

Comment: The code is correct, but the first sentence is not. The argument to defaultdict creates the values, not the keys.